# Show full drop-down list, but only populate field with characters before a "-"?

Tags: excel, validation

I am attempting to create a drop-down list populated with a range from another sheet.  But what I want to do is show the full list, and when the user selects and item, it will only enter into that cell all characters before the dash.

So, if I had "David - Project Manager" upon selection the cell with populate with just "David" and remove everything after the dash.  Everything after is just there to make things easier to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a [Contextures Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLJEMnIT0zM).

There is a link to the code needed on the sheet in a downloadable XLS file.

```
Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo errHandler
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
If Target.Column = 6 Then
  If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo exitHandler
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Target.Value = Worksheets("codes").Range("C1").Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, Worksheets("codes").Range("activitycodes"), 0) - 1, -2)
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

errHandler:
  If Err.Number = 13 Or Err.Number = 1004 Then
    GoTo exitHandler
  Else
    Resume Next
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `Data Validation`. VBA could be used to modify the validated cell (but that would break the validation, wouldn't it?) How about a compromise where `Data Validation` provides the full entry, then an adjacent cell trims it down to your requirement, which I believe is:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)-1)),A1)
```

Where `A1` is a cell containing `Data Validation`

Answer (score 0):

The VBA method doesn't break the validation since VBA can go around those requirements.  Assuming the range of cells with the DV to adjust is B2:B100, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B100")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B100"))
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "-") > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            cell.Value = Trim(Left(cell.Value, InStr(1, cell.Value, "-") - 1))
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next cell
End If

End Sub
```

That macro goes into the SHEET module.

Comment: Can't get this working.  All I've changed is the Range to refer to the named range which holds my list values.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that is incorrect, change the range to refer to the cells on the sheet where you're using the DV drop list.  Make sure this macro is IN that sheet module.